# Alternate exits in Bit Trip Runner 2

Tags: runner2

Is there any point in taking the alternate exits in Bit Trip Runner 2?  I can't see any benefit to doing so in terms of unlocking a different path in the overworld, so is it just for your own benefit?

Answer (score 3):

Each alternate exit (marked with blue arrow) unlocks a path to one side level. This levels are not required for story progression but can give you the following:

- New playable character;
- New costume;
- Gold (thus increasing gold count to help open other side levels that require gold);
- Trophies\achievements (some of them require clearing side levels);
- Just fun from running around and jumping over stuff;

If you`re not interested in any of this, then taking blue route is not worth it.